# Android: Parsing JSONArray of a JSONObject but still get syntax Error

Tags: java, android

i've read alot about parsing json in android and i don't know where i missed because i thinks that i do it right but it's keep showing me error

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "category_name": "Kiehn, Kohler and Russel",
            "created_at": "2018-08-29 05:35:50",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-29 05:35:50"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "category_name": "Flatley PLC",
            "created_at": "2018-08-29 05:35:50",
            "updated_at": "2018-08-29 05:35:50"
        }]
}
```

And here is my handle in android

```
try {
               ArrayList<TagModel> tagdata = new ArrayList<>();
               JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);                   
               //Category
               ArrayList<CategoryModel> catedata = new ArrayList<>();
               JSONArray catearray = object.getJSONArray("categories");
               for (int i = 0; i < catearray.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject product = catearray.getJSONObject(i);
                  CategoryModel recommend_model = new CategoryModel();
                  recommend_model.setCategoryName(product.getString("category_name"));
                  recommend_model.setCategoryId(String.valueOf(product.getInt("id")));
                  catedata.add(recommend_model);
               }                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

The Error keep telling the same issue that is:

> at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
>           at org.json.JSONTokener.readObject(JSONTokener.java:393)
>           at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:100)
>           at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:159)
>           at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:176)
>           at kh.com.example.sopheak_pc.CenturyRecipe.Data.DataClass$1.onResponse(DataClass.java:44)
>   08-30 06:47:37.283 22712-22712/kh.com.example.sopheak_pc.CenturyRecipe
>   W/System.err:     at
>   kh.com.example.sopheak_pc.CenturyRecipe.Data.DataClass$1.onResponse(DataClass.java:38)

Here is the full log message: 
[image: Log Error]

and when i debug, the error start from
 `JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);`

and it's going to

```
 catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

*Sorry if it's a bit messy because i want to show everywhere that relate to the error Thanks you!!!*

i've just found my error inside string json and here what it's look like
[image: Here is what i found the error]

Comment: Are you *sure* that is the JSON text it is trying to parse when the error occurs? Because that JSON looks ok. Try printing the actual JSON before the stacktrace, then test the output e.g. on https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: As Andreas said make sure the response variable is a valid JSON string. It could be a problem with non-escaped quotation marks?

Comment: @Andreas after you point out, i've just read my Json and there is a little error between my json and it's said **W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 74646 of ** and after this error it's show my json

Comment: @Sam Littlefair i've update my second photo of the error

Comment: Copy the whole JSON into an online validator and see what it says. If there's nothing wrong, you may need to escape all the double quotes, replacing `"` with `\"`.

Comment: @Sam Littlefair thanks you for your time. the error is got from the json string value itself. now i've update the answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Andreas and @Sam Littlefair mention is my json contain "," inside the string so i clean up my data and enter simple data and it's working fine now! Thanks you 2 of you!

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted!